# setTimeout sometimes becomes crazy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a kind of slideshow that is updated with a function like this :

```
function updateSlide(x,y) {
    slide = getNextSlide(x);
    setTimeout(updateSlide, 1000 * slide.duration, slide, y);
}
```

But sometimes, after a moment, the browser (Chrome in my case) doesn't respect the duration, and it becomes worst and worst. It can be 2 seconds instead of 10, or 20 seconds instead of 2 minutes.

I don't know if it's related but I have another script using setTimeout running every 2 seconds running in parallel.

Any fix for this kind of behavior ?

Comment: Do a `console.log(slide.duration);` to see what you are actually asking for. By the way, `setTimeout` only takes 2 parameters.

Comment: What are the `y` and `z` parameters in the `setTimeout` function for? This function only takes two parameters.

Comment: I guess this behaviour iniated when you run `updateSlide(x,y,z)` second and more times. Just add fourth parameter `no_auto_timeout` and when you calling this function more tan one times set it to 0.

Comment: @ExoSkeleton321 `setTimeout` accepts additional parameters beyond the delay which are then passed to the function upon calling it.

Comment: @James Thorpe Oh ok, never knew that actually.

Comment: `setTimeout` takes as many parameters as you like [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: However the parameters listed here don't seem to match - function takes 3, but only 2 are being passed.  @user2223898 - I think we need more context on the data structures you're using and what `y` and `z` are, but on the face of it it seems like you have some mismatching parameters at least.

Comment: What does `getNextSlide(undefined);` return? Because that is what you get after 3 calls. A call to `u(x,y,z);`, followed by `u(y, z, undefined)`, followed by `u(z, undefined, undefined)` followed by `u(undefined, undefined, undefined);`.

Comment: I am sure you are calling the function updateSlide(x,y,z) multiple times.

Comment: @James Thorpe, Sumurai8, Paul Wasilewski : I've made a mistake when writing a simplified version of my  function, but it works. The slideshow can run for several days without problem, or can become crazy after 10 minutes, but I'm sure my real function is correct.